# is -nU an option with nmap?

Tags: nmap, udp

My coworkers seem to have -nU (no udp) as an option for their nmap scripts but I've never seen this in use and when I try to use this option with nmap, it does not work. I thought no udp was enabled by default and -sU had to be used for udp to be scanned. Is this correct?

Comment: nothing in the man pages either

Comment: Perhaps your co-workers have added that option themselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-nU` is not a valid Nmap option. You are correct that UDP will only be scanned if you use the `-sU` option.